# "The Plesk's name server acts as the primary name server for the DNS zone". What does that mean?

Tags: dns, plesk

One of my co-workers just got all confused and mixed up, because when he went to the DNS section of the plesk control panel (provided by our web host), it told him that

```
 "The Plesk's DNS server acts as a primary name server for the DNS zone <our zone name>"
```

Well, the web-host name-server was not our authoritative name server, and adding records there had no material effect on what users saw. But a "primary" domain name server is normally just the first name server that your workstation or service queries. Which leads me to the questions:

Is there something on a Plesk /Wordpress /joomla / Drupal website that would use a 'primary' name server?  What does it mean "for  domain"? Is this all just misleading and confusing, or if not, what does it mean?

Comment: In a nutshell, Plesk will provide DNS services for your domain so it will resolve to your hosting account/website. This depends on if you are using the nameservers that Plesk configured for you or not. You can do a DNS lookup [here](https://network-tools.com/) to tell if it contains your Plesk nameservers or not. If you don't see them there, then you're likely using nameservers provided by an external DNS service. In that case, you can ignore the DNS settings in Plesk since only the DNS provider's that you're using will matter.

Comment: "But a "primary" domain name server is normally just the first name server that your workstation or service queries. " This mixes up authoritative nameservers and recursive nameservers. And the message you quote from Plesk use sloppy sentences as for authoritative nameservers from the outside it is not relevant which one is "primary" and which are "secondaries",  a difference that may not even exist anymore. As for the recursive one, indeed any computer has at least one nameserver it contacts to resolve name on its behalf, but this is clearly not what Plesk message is about.